# Auto frame rate ffmpeg when passing frame with pipe

Tags: ffmpeg, phantomjs

I am using phantom js to render screenshots of the page and then passing it to FFmpeg to create a video, is it possible to make FFmpeg auto calculate the framerate using the duration between frames?

```
phantomjs file.js | ffmpeg -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 30 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart outp.mp4
```

I tried to make phantomjs send frame every 1/30 seconds but because it's in a setIntervale it doesn't work like expected.

Comment: Remove the `-r 30` and add `-vsync 0` before `outp.mp4`.

Comment: For some reason the video is faster, when I input the timestamps with phantomjs I can see that from the first frame to last one there are 25 seconds but when passed to FFmpeg I got a video of 7-8 seconds

Comment: If you're receiving the input via image2pipe, there should be no timestamps conveyed to ffmpeg. IIRC, with vsync 0, it will use wallclock but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Got any updates on this , am stumbling upon the same issue.

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you for your help. I am having the same issue, with `-vsync 0` and `image2pipe`, the output video file is faster.

Comment: If you know the framerate is 30, add `-framerate 30` in place of `-r 30` in the OP's command and check.